# どうせだったら, どうせなら and どうせだから

Tags: word-choice, usage

どうせだから seems to occur more when some sort of causality is in place or some sort of explanation is expected, and it also often appears as a standalone sentence. And I guess どうせだったら would be more likely to appear as a statement of condition. But the line seems blurry, considering both are similarly defined as "might as well", so I wonder if they are interchangeable in some sentences.

> しかも、中途半端な男にいって振られるのが嫌だったら、どうせだったらめっちゃいい男にいったほうがいいよね。([source](https://logmi.jp/business/articles/173336))

Can どうせだから be used here? What about どうせなら?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. In this case,

> しかも、中途半端な男にいって振られるのが嫌だったら、どうせだったらめっちゃいい男にいったほうがいいよね

If you use the どうせだから, it could imply that you're going to be rejected anyway. Like,

> どうせ（振られるの）だから...

On the other hand, if you use どうせだったら, "*If there is a possibility that you will be rejected anyway...*" comes to my mind first (for me personally). Like,

> どうせ（振られる可能性があるの）だったら...

I think the original sentence was meant to say, "*If you don't want to confess to a half-baked guy and get rejected, it's still better to confess to a nice guy and get rejected anyway.*" When I translate it into English like that, it doesn't seem to make much difference whether if we use "どうせだから" or "どうせだったら," but when it's in Japanese, I feel required to read the true meaning between the words, which is a strangely sophisticated thing to do.

I'll leave this answer for now, hoping that others will come up with a more excellent answer. The answer mine looks more like based on my feeling.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. +1 I just thought of another that I might as well add to the list: どうせなら. Would you address that as well?

Comment: @EddieKal I think どうせなら can fit there, as it can be どうせ（振られる可能性がある）なら... Actually I thought I'd add どうせなら and どのみち (as it can be どのみち振られる可能性があるなら...) in my answer while writing it, but I felt I'm not so good at explaining those in English, lol. Anyway, both どうせなら and どのみち can fit there, IMO. Somehow, どうせだから can't be there, at least for me. Some may argue, some may agree.